# Determine the type of an uninitialized array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, typename

I want to write a function that, when given a declared but uninitialized array for a user-defined class, the function will identify the type of objects the array is designed to hold, and then create new objects for the array.
I have a class called "clsNewSector", and I declare an array in another class like this:

```
Private pSectors(1 To 3) As clsNewSector
```

Then I have a function that should be able to identify that although every object references "Nothing" at the moment, it should be able to get the type of the array, which in this case is clsNewSector, but in other cases the class type might change.

```
Function InitializeObjectArray(a As Variant) As Variant
Dim NameofType As String
NameOfType = TypeName(a(1))
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    Set a(i) = NewObject(NameOfType)
Next i
End Function
```

The typename function does not work because it just returns "Nothing" since the array is uninitialized, it is unable to identify that the variable was declared as a different type. Is there any way to find the declared type of an uninitialized array so that I can then use a for loop to initialize each member of the array with the correct type of new object.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon , but that still doesn't resolve the problem of creating different objects based on the array that is passed into the function.

Comment: I think what Mathieu is saying is that you're approaching this *the wrong way*, and that your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BigBen correct, this isn't a problem that is *supposed* to even have a need to be solved, it's a problem *created* by the false need to have a function that is responsible for creating different types of objects based on type metadata that doesn't exist: another approach is necessary IMO.

Comment: Typename will work (in a manner) if you provide the array variable rather than a member of the array.  Unfortunately, in the case of objects (of any type) the typename  returned from an uninitialised array will be  'Object().

Comment: Any implementation I can think of for `NewObject` implies a `Select Case` block involving an ever-increasing amount of likely heterogeneous and unrelated data types, and thus coupling the function/module to as many classes, so the smell is really the high level of *coupling* induced by the approach - the general idea is a good one (increase the *abstraction level* / reduce the verbosity of higher-level code), but going meta with the type system in VBA quickly hits language limitations...

Answer (score 1):

The question the OP is asking is essentially about initialising an object which is  (in this case) a collection of clsNewSector.

An easy way to do this is to wrap a scripting.dictionary in a strongly types Class.

The code below is for an object called clsNewSectors which will create an object containing a scripting dictionary holding three clsNewSector objects.

The Item property of the scripting dictionary is strongly typed so that we can only add, set or get clsNewSector objects.

If you examine the code below you can see it can be repurposed for different objects by doing a search and replace on ClsNewSector only (assuming an integer long key is still acceptable)

**Class clsNewSectors**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type State
    
    Host As Scripting.dictionary
    
End Type

Private s As State



Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set s.Host = New Scripting.dictionary
    
    With s.Host
    
        .Add .Count, New clsNewSector
        .Add .Count, New clsNewSector
        .Add .Count, New clsNewSector
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(ByVal ipIndex As Long) As clsNewSector

    If s.Host.exists(ipIndex) Then
    
        Set Item = s.Host.Item(ipIndex)
        
    Else
    
        Err.Raise 381, "Invalid index", "The index does not exist"
        
    End If
        
End Property


Public Property Set Item(ByVal ipIndex As Long, ByVal ipValue As clsNewSector)

    ' Avoid creating a dictionary entry by assignment
    If s.Host.exists(ipIndex) Then
    
        Set s.Host.Item(ipIndex) = ipValue
        
    Else
    
        Err.Raise 381, "Invalid index", "The index does not exist"
        
    End If
        
End Property

Public Sub Add(ByVal ipKey As Long, ByVal ipItem As clsNewSector)

    If s.Host.exists(ipKey) Then
    
        Err.Raise 457, "Key error", "A value is already associated with the key"
        
    End If
    
    s.Host.Add ipKey, ipItem
    
End Sub

Public Function Keys() As Variant

    Keys = s.Host.Keys
    
End Function

Public Function Items() As Variant

    Items = s.Host.Items
    
End Function
```

The OP original code can now be replaced with

```
Private pSectors As clsNewSectors
Set pSectors = new clsNewSectors
```

This idea above can be extended to add more flexibility (such as a factory for multiple types of object) but that's a separate discussion.

The code above compiles OK and does not generate any RUbberduck inspections of significance.

The code above requires a reference to the Microsoft Scripting RUntime.

Comment: Is there an advantage to Dictionary vs Collection?

Comment: @BrianMStafford good question. If you don't need to access or iterate the keys, a `Collection` works perfectly well to wrap into a custom collection class.

Comment: The advantage to a Scripting.Dictionary is the 'exists' method and also the fact that that you can retrieve arrays of the Keys or Items through the Keys and Items methods.  This can be very useful if you are pushing data back to excel for example.  If you don't need these facilities then a Collection is fine.  In the code I provided above above I forgot to add the functions for count and exists in the wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

The array *is* initialized:

```
Private pSectors(1 To 3) As clsNewSector
```

Its individual elements aren't assigned, but the array itself is ready for whatever you want to throw at it: it's reserving 3 spots for `clsNewSector` instances, at compile-time. Being an object type, the array is merely holding *pointers*. Under the hood, VBA arrays point to a [`SAFEARRAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearray) structure that look something like this:

```
typedef struct tagSAFEARRAY {
  USHORT         cDims;
  USHORT         fFeatures;
  ULONG          cbElements;
  ULONG          cLocks;
  PVOID          pvData;
  SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
} SAFEARRAY;
```

The type metadata for any given element is only accessible via a series of successive pointer reads; the array structure itself is abstracting away the concept of a *type* of element, such that it's capable of supporting *any* type. [This content](https://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-array-variables-and-pointers-in-depth/) (not mine) goes into further details.

Whether a programming language might let a `Foo` into an array of `Bar` objects is all about *type safety*, which . In .NET (and other techs), type safety is very extensively explored, with generics and other advanced mechanisms. In VBA, we're 25 years ago, with a compiler that defers a lot of type safety to last-minute runtime checks - this code compiles perfectly fine:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim things(1 To 10) As Class1
    Set things(1) = New Class2 '<~ *run-time* error 13 "type mismatch"
End Sub
```

Now, if there's some level of *run-time* type safety, surely that means the type metadata exists *somewhere*! And it does - but VBA does not have an extensive type system surfaced to the language, and much of its internal mechanics aren't [easily] programmatically accessible (call stack comes to mind).

In any function call, the arguments are evaluated first - so when we do `TypeName(a(1))`, the `a(1)` subscript resolves to a NULL object pointer (no reference was `Set` yet), so `Nothing` is passed to the `TypeName` function, which returns the string `"Nothing"` since VBA has pretty weird typing semantics in this area - but if we leave the type of individual elements alone for a minute and look at the data type of the array itself...

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim things(1 To 10) As Class1
    Debug.Print TypeName(things) ' prints "Object()"
End Sub
```

The fact that the reported data type of our explicitly-typed array is `Object()` tells us everything we need to know: the real type metadata *of the array itself* is being abstracted away, so there is no [simple?] VBA code that can be given an array and an object variable, and determine whether the object is of the correct type for the array, unless we hard-code the expected data type *and don't care for null references*.

The problem we're facing here, is that the reason we need to determine a specific data type is to spawn a new object of that type - and since object references initialize to `Nothing`, that's the only "data type" we'll only get.

Unless we initialize the array differently.

You could make `clsNewSector` have a *default instance* (set its `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute value to `True`, or just use and synchronize Rubberduck's [`@PredeclaredId` annotation](https://rubberduckvba.com/Annotations/Details/PredeclaredId), and then expose a property like these:

```
Public Property Get IsDefault() As Boolean
    IsDefault = Me Is clsNewSector
End Property
```

And then you could initialize `pSectors` with pointers to the class' default instance as soon as possible:

```
For i = LBound(pSectors) To UBound(pSectors)
    Set pSectors(i) = clsNewSector
Next
```

That way no subscript would default to `Nothing` when you pass `a(1)` to `TypeName`, and then the rest of the code is cursed with having to verify whether the instance they're looking at has `IsDefault = True`, otherwise we run the risk of making that global default instance *stateful*, and we wouldn't want that to happen (shared global state at various array indices - what could possibly go wrong?!).

Overall pretty frail, definitely not ideal.

An idiomatic solution would be to [create a custom collection class per type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63120695/1188513), that gets to enforce type safety on its own terms. Could be a `NewSectors` class (consider dropping that `cls` prefix) whose `Item` indexed `Property Set` member will throw an error given `Nothing` or any object reference that isn't a `NewSector` instance.

---

The root of the problem is the too many *apparent* responsibilities of the `NewObject` function, which seemingly can create anything given a string with a type name.

**Let's think outside the box for a minute.**

> ```
> Function InitializeObjectArray(a As Variant) As Variant
> ```

We use the array `a` itself to get the name of a type, and then we pass that name to a function that gets us the object of the type we expect.

So the function is inherently coupled with `NewObject`, whose name isn't telling us much about the breadth of its applicability.

#### This looks like a job for...

What if we moved that responsibility to a formalized interface?

```
@Interface IArrayItemFactory
Option Explicit

Public Function Create() As Object
End Function
```

Then we could have a `NewSectorFactory` class that implements it as follows:

```
Implements IArrayItemFactory
Option Explicit

Private Function IArrayItemFactory_Create() As Object
    Set IArrayItemFactory_Create = New clsNewSector
End Function
```

Now `InitializeObjectArray` might look like this:

```
Public Function InitializeObjectArray(ByVal a As Variant, ByVal factory As IArrayItemFactory) As Variant
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        Set a(i) = factory.Create
    Next i
End Function
```

By stripping the function of the responsibility of working out the type of object to create, and moving it into its own object/dependency, the function is now easily able to initialize any array of any object type that has an implementation for the `IArrayItemFactory` interface, and *the calling code* is now responsible for telling the function what to initialize the array with, by simply being responsible for providing the implementation for the factory.